# Reading and casting as given type from XML / XSD

Tags: xml, types, casting, xsd, schema

I would like to read data like:

```
<Field surname="Smith"/>
<Field age="11"/>
<Field home_owner="false"/>
```

in such a way that I can have a "Field" class with just Name & Value properties. The caveat being that the value will be of varying type as defined in the XSD eg

```
<xs:attribute name="home_owner" type="xs:boolean" use="optional">
<xs:attribute name="surname" type="xs:string" use="optional">
<xs:attribute name="age" type="xs:string" use="optional">
```

Now, I can use  attr.GetSchemaInfo().SchemaAttribute.AttributeSchemaType.Datatype.ValueType to get the type, but I don't know how best to use this information to cast it.

Is this a good idea? Or would it make more sense to look at each field type individually?

Comment: what Framework are you using ? (attr.GetSchemaInfo().SchemaAttribute.AttributeSchemaType.Datatype.ValueType)

Comment: Presumably the capital letters at the start of method names means this is C# rather than Java?